# DownloadFileCompleted event not working while asynchronously downloading files using webclient

Tags: c#, webclient

I am downloading 4 files asynchronously  using Webclient. The problem is that in this scenrio, it doesn't fire FileCompletedEvent when any file is completed.

Don't worry about the code ,i have removed a lot of extra code .it must work for single file at a time

```
 Dictionary<int, WebClient> wd = new Dictionary<int, WebClient>();


 public void DownloadPDF(string url,string path)
    {
        index=1;
        if (wd.ContainsKey(1) == false)
        {
            wd.Add(1, null);
        }
                for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++)
                {
                    if (wd[i] == null)
                    {
                        wd[i] = new WebClient();
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
             wd[index].DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, e) =>    w_DownloadFileCompleted(sender, e, path,index);


             wd[index].DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), path);
     }

private void w_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e, string path,int index)
    {
        wd[index] = null;
    }
```

This question is different from other in case of scenario of downloading concurrent files. Thank you

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Sorry that was already local .I just misplaced the position of line while coping the code

Answer (score 0):

Did you give AsyncCompletedEventHandler a shot?

Comment: What does that mean ,sorry didn't understand

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx